# Fourier transform of $te^{-t^2}$?

Tags: functions, fourier-analysis, integral-transforms

How can I find the Fourier transform of:

$$f(t) = te^{-t^2}$$

Comment: what have you tried? do you know what is the Fourier transform of $e^{-t^2}$. Then what happens if you multiply by a t? (see 107 in this link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Convolution_theorem under functional relationship)

Comment: Can you tell us what notation do you use for Fourier transform? Is it $\displaystyle F(\omega)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)e^{-i\omega t}dt$?

Comment: @Lost1 Thanks! Never spotted these down there.

Comment: no worries. it is just a consequence of the fact multiplying ik is the same as differentiating.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If using the Fourier transform $\hat{f}(\xi) = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)e^{-2\pi i x\xi}dx$,
then $x^nf(x) $ has the Fourier transform $\left(\frac{i}{2\pi}\right)^n\frac{d^n\hat{f}(\xi)}{d\xi}$,
and $f(x) = e^{-\alpha x^2}$ has the Fourier transform $\hat{f}(\xi) = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\alpha}}e^{-(\pi\xi)^2/\alpha}$.

What happens if you try to combine them?